# Identifying Audio bit rate using FFMPEG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to identify the bit rate of an audio file in my Rails app.  I am downloading the file from S3, and storing temporarily in the tmp folder, then running FFMPEG commands against it.

Locally everything is running absolutely as expected.  The problem comes when deploying, and I get nothing returned from FFMPEG.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
:access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
:secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

object = s3.buckets[ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]].objects[CGI::unescape(self.url)]

tempname = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(DateTime.now.to_s) + "." + self.file_format
File.open(Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/' + tempname, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(object.read)
end

dl = Rails.root.to_s + '/tmp/' + tempname
brcommand = "ffmpeg -i " + dl + " 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'"
ffmpeg = %x{#{brcommand}}
```

I am using %x{ffmpeg_command} to access the command line, so I'm wandering whether that may be causing the problem where it is not finding the file as if it had been running natively in Rails.

I have used FFMPEG on the command line on the server, so I know it is working fine.

Comment: and is the files written to a `tmp` folder?

Comment: You might want to use [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) instead.

Comment: Yes, the file is written using the File.open syntax.

Comment: Will take a look at ffprobe, as this may make things easier or could uncover where the problem is originating

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use ffprobe with JSON output like this example:

> ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format Ramp\ -\ Apathy.mp3

Which produces the follwing output:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "Ramp - Apathy.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "203.638856",
        "size": "4072777",
        "bit_rate": "159999",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Apathy",
            "artist": "Ramp",
            "album": "Evolution Devolution Revolution",
            "date": "1999",
            "genre": "Metal"
        }
    }
}
```